# Change HTML element on scroll Magic

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollmagic

*[scroll Magic](http://scrollmagic.io/)* is a great tool for animation on scroll.

CSS, GSAP and velocity animation work Great.

> But is it possible to change HTML text on scroll.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e3daqyjh/)**

on scroll circular radius is moving and in the same time. I want to change 1 number should count 2 and 3 and 'year' should become years on 2 and 3 number. It should be like preloader on scroll.

This is possible By CSS show and hide but I want to do this with HTML in scrollMagic. Just wondering is it possible.

Code has to be there with fiddle that's why putting it.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var yearChange = new TimelineMax()
    .fromTo(".year-loader", 1, {rotation:'0'}, {rotation:'720', ease: Linear.ease});
    var yearCount = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement:'#section',
        triggerHook:0,
        duration:'200%'
    })
    .setTween(yearChange)
    .setPin('.yearCounter', {pushFollowers: false})
    .addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't go in detail in scrollMagic API.
That's a option to change HTML.

`onStart: function () {$tText.html("2"); $year.html("years")}`

[**Solve Fiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/e3daqyjh/4/)